# How to put all c-functions from .dll into a c++ class?

Tags: c++, c, adapter, wrapper, extern

I need to write a wrapper-class to use the functionality of one of the C-library, I found this solution, but it's kinda strange and I feel there is some easy way to do it. Here is the way that I found

```c
extern "C" {
    #include <some_dll_lib.h> //take all functions from lib
}

class Wrapper {
public:
    //creating definition for each function, but with different names
    Type* another_name_for_C_function_1(); 
    Type* another_name_for_C_function_2();
    //and so on...
};

Type* Wrapper::another_name_for_C_function1()
{
    return real_name_C_function1_from_included_C_lib();//in function-definition use function from C-lib
}

Type* Wrapper::another_name_for_C_function2()
{
    return real_name_C_function2_from_included_C_lib();
}
```

It's really sad if this is the only way to do things like this.

Comment: Why do you think you need a `class`? What would different instances of this class represent? What state does it hold? Why do you think you have to do this to begin with? It might even help if you gave concrete info, like the C library in question and the names used therein.

Comment: Could simply include the C header into a namespace be an option? It may not work if you have complex dependencies, but should be damned simple for a simple include file...

Comment: That would cause the functions to be declared inside the namespace, but the definitions would still be in the global namespace (the only one available to C), so linking would fail, @SergeBallesta.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt hate to tell it, but I don't see any point in it either. This is a university assignment. They force me to write a wrapper class for whatever c libraries I use and then through the Adapter-pattern use it's wrapper. I asking that just for sure that it's the only way to do it

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: I do not agree.  There will be no definition in the C++ world, and the `extern "C"` will ensure correct linking. I have just tested it and it works fine in both CLang and MSVC.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Sorry. but I need a class, not a namespace. That's the problem

Comment: @LDr: It is uncommon for a wrapper class to only contain static functions, the reason why I proposed a simple namespace. It would probably be easier if you showed a slightly more realistic example of your requirement.

Comment: @SergeBallesta well, yes, it contains not only a static functions, but what's the difference? I still don't understand how can I wrap it into a C++ class.

Comment: @LDr: In the Windows world, the MFC classes give an example of what could be wrappers around C functions: the C data structures become the classes, and the functions using them become *naturally* member functions.

Comment: @SergeBallesta sounds like what I need

Comment: You will still need to manually write all these wrapper methods. You could write a script in any language to try to automate this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal example of wrapping a C data structure and a function using it into a C class:

foo.h

```
struct foo {
    int a;
    int b;
};

int bar(struct foo*);
```

foo.c (will go into the C dll)

```
#include "foo.h"

int bar(struct foo* x) {
    return x->a + x->b;
}
```

wrapper.h:

```
extern "C" {
#include "foo.h"
}
class Wrapper {
    foo x;
public:
    Wrapper(int a, int b);
    int bar();
};
```

wrapper.cpp:

```
#include "wrapper.h"

Wrapper::Wrapper(int a, int b): x(foo{a, b}) {}
int Wrapper::bar() {
    return ::bar(&x);
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "wrapper.h"


int main() {
    Wrapper w {1, 2};
    std::cout << w.bar() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Am i right that in the same time you can use bar() from foo.h and use w.bar() from wrapper.h?